# Is it possible to load images in Picasso from non-standard URL's

Tags: android, picasso

I am trying to get Picasso to work with non-standard image URLs.

I am currently implementing this the following way:

```
String url = "http://someexampledomain.com/gallery.php?action=photo&phid=213"

Picasso.with(viewGroup.getContext()).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar_circular).error(R.drawable.default_avatar_circular).into(holder.postPhoto);
```

The above code results in the error placeholder image being loaded. (Please note that the link I have provided is a dummy link. I can't provide the actual link as it is a private API).

The following works however:

```
String url = "http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100125172609/starwars/images/thumb/f/f3/Yoda_naturist.jpg/200px-Yoda_naturist.jpg."

Picasso.with(viewGroup.getContext()).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar_circular).error(R.drawable.default_avatar_circular).into(holder.postPhoto);
```

I have not changed anything else, except the format of the URL. The first url works in my browser. Does Picasso not support URL's of the first type?

Comment: I would appreciate if people could explain why the post is being voted down in the comments if possible.

Comment: @Selvin I've amended the question. The problematic URL mentioned in the question does work in my web browser (Chrome).

Comment: *does work in WB* means nothing ... Picasso is for images not html ...

Comment: The URL you are trying to access, does it have its headers set as an image type?

Comment: @MrPablo Yes, I checked with the API dev and he confirmed this.

Comment: @Selvin I just wanted to mention that the link was working and it wasn't broken etc. If you have nothing constructive to add to this, please refrain from commenting on this question.

Comment: @MrPablo To further clarify, I checked the Dev Tools in Chrome and it shows the request for the image as Type: image/png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back and forth, the API dev and I realised that this could potentially be a server side authentication issue. After some investigation this proved to be the case.

Altering the request URL with the appropriate authentication credentials resulted in the image loading successfully via Picasso.

I thought I'd mention this here in the event someone else ran into a similar issue.